# Init anonymous function of directive instance

Tags: angularjs

In directive we can define the isolate scope so that it can be reused

```
var app = angular.module('myModule',[])
.directive('btn',[function(){
    return {
        ...,
        scope:{}
    }
}]);
```

In usage, it can create separate instance.

```
<scope>
    <btn></btn>
    <btn></btn>
</scope>
```

However, if the `<btn>` has events like 'click', 'hover' etc. and those event should be defined in the scope or controller at the very first beginning. If I have many `<btn>` and they are placed at different files, I have to defined as many handlers as the number of `<btn>` in one file. That means the page has to load lots of unnecessary functions.

Are there any method can let me initialize the instance of the directive so that it can accept anonymous function to become its handler before it render that direction. Like:

```
<scope>
    <btn>this_btn.click=function(){alert(1)}</btn>
    <btn>this_btn.hover=function(){alert(0)}</btn>
<scope>
```

Comment: nothing here stops you from using native directives like `ng-click`, i.e. `<btn ng-click=""></btn>`. Have you tried using those?

Comment: yes, I know that, but the problem is the same. For using ng-click, I still need to defined the function at the beginning in a directive or the scope. however, once I define the specific function in directive, it can't be reused anymore.

Comment: if a specific function needs to be shared between multiple directives, that function should be in a service and be injected into the directives that require it. It doesn't need to be defined in the directive or in the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define functions in the html. scope is an abstraction of the DOM; it represents a piece of it, so adding functions in the scope is the angular way of putting them in the DOM.

That said, you can just add behaviour in the already existing directives.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <input type="text" ng-model="text">
  {{text}}
  <btn ng-click="text = 1">on click</button>
  <btn ng-mouseenter="text = 2"> on hover</button>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, I tried. But it seems can't accept anonymous function as attributes like ng-click="(function(){alert(0)})()". it will throw exceptions.

Comment: I strongly advice you against it. Why do you want this spaguetti?

Comment: because I am trying to find the way to normalize it. If there exist a way to init the instance of a directive, it can minimize the loading and maintenance. For example, btn.init({click:sth}) or btn.init({hover:sth}). I just can use 'require' to closely achieve.

Comment: when I use 'require':'btn' to create a directive, <btn new-directive></btn> it can closely achieve what i want. However, the scope in link will be massed up since if I specify scop:{} for the new directive, It becomes a completely separate directive and will throw multiple directive error. In this case I cannot access the $scope of 'btn'.